# Why, when raised to the level of the array and divide it to another array of numbers is obtained, rather than an array?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab

Why, in the Matlab in the construction of the power of the array and divide it into another array (with the same number of values) obtained just a number, not an array? That line of code:

```
cvDelta = sdDelta.^2/delta;
```

How to recreate this code in Python? In Python, when doing this line:

```
cvDelta = sdDelta ** 2 / delta
```

then I do not get a number and get an array.

Answer (score 1):

For a matlab like experience you should consider using numpy. Following code would do the trick

```
import numpy as np
# Define sdDelta and Delta
sdDelta = np.array(sdDelta)
Delta = np.array(Delta)
cvDelta = sdDelta ** 2 / delta
```

Comment: Tried your option - the output array, rather than a single number, as in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

This should make it

`[sdDelta[i]**2/delta[i] for i in range(len(delta))]`

Or more readable for me

`[x**2/y for x,y in zip(sdDelta, delta)]`

Comment: Tried your option - the output array, rather than a single number, as in MATLAB. In MATLAB the result is a single number (not an array).

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood your question. Can you explain what kind of single number you want to obtain and how to calculeate it? In pseudocode for example.

Comment: In Matlab is a single number is calculated as follows: `cvDelta = sdDelta.^2/delta;` Here, before the exponentiation present symbol of the "dot". I do not know what it means, but without a script in Matlab does not work.